# What maneuvers can a non-pilot perform when flying with a private pilot?

Tags: flight-training, general-aviation, passenger

I recently got my private pilot license and will soon be taking people for rides. My son wants to get his license (he passed his written test), so I was thinking I could introduce him so basic maneuvers. As a pilot, but not an instructor, what can I safely let a non-pilot do? Obviously anything in the pattern will require myself to be in control, but is it OK for a non-pilot to do slow flight or steep turns? Or would it be better to just perform them myself and let them see how its done? As pilot in command, it comes down to what I feel is safe, but are there any regulations that prevents a passenger from taking the controls and doing some turns? I don't remember this being covered in ground school or any of the training books.

Comment: See also [Are pilots allowed to let passengers fly the plane?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3039/556)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but this question is more in line with what training maneuvers can a non-instructor allow a non-pilot to perform. Are there any regs that limit what a pilot can let their passenger can do? Suppose someone has an aerobatic plane, can a non-instructor allow a non-pilot do loops?

Comment: This question is really a dupe of the other one: whether you're 'training' your son or not is irrelevant, you're still the pilot and he's still a passenger, so it's up to you to determine what's safe and what isn't. Since you just got your PPL yourself, you might want to consider if you can demonstrate maneuvers effectively at all. You might inadvertently introduce him to some bad habits and - unless you're a teacher yourself - you haven't been trained to teach. You may also not have the experience/training to recognize a potentially dangerous situation developing.

Comment: Is the question about regulations in some locale or about what can safely be done? You might want to clarify the question and highlight how you think it differs from the previous one.

Comment: Old topic, but I'd say he can do pretty much anything not requiring a parachute, and probably best to stay out of airspace where radio work is required to start.  As you're not a CFI, he can't log any of the hours as Dual Received either.

Comment: Since this is already answered, you can view there, but I'll say this out of concern for your safety - while the PIC can legally let a non-pilot fly, this is something that you should ease into as a low time pilot. You should let a non pilot do maneuvers like slow flight or steep turns, as they are potentially dangerous maneuvers, and as a low time private pilot, you do not have the experience to reliably account for every mistake they could make. You could alternatively do them yourself, but allow your son to follow the controls.