# Can I pilot a plane while having a chronic mental health condition?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilots, medical, student-pilot

I want to claim to have flown, it is a dream of mine.

My medical condition disqualifies me from being a pilot. I have one of the following ADHD/OCD/depression/mania/bipolar. Is there a way I can fly as a copilot without a pilot's license?

I want something preferably cheap and not a simulator.

Comment: Have you considered ultralights?

Comment: @GdD do you have experience with such.  Although they don't require a license I almost feel there is bigger risk on ultralights because there is nobody there to try and take over.  We they even let me fly one to begin with?  I am living in NC and have found the following http://piedmontaerosports.com/

Comment: I am not an ultralight pilot, but if I was in a position where I couldn't get a medical I would consider them. They are the cheapest powered option available by far. They are inherently less safe I think, but no flying is risk free. The EAA has a page you may want to read: http://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aviation-communities-and-interests/ultralights-and-ultralight-aircraft/getting-started-in-ultralight-flying/ultralight-training-resources/fixed-wing-ultralight-training

Comment: Are you asking specifically about flying with a licensed pilot, or about flying an airplane solo?

Comment: @GdD solo preferred for obvious reasons.  Should I ask 2 questions?  This question has become more about flying with a licensed pilot then the other.

Comment: I think you should edit it to ask "what kind of flying can I do if I can't pass a medical". It's not 2 questions really.

Comment: In the US ultralights do require a sport pilot license. The sport license just doesn't require a medical

Comment: Yes, as long as the "medical condition" is not blindness.

Comment: I hope the FBI has flags for crap like this.  Who wants this guy flying by their house?

Comment: @blankip haha in all seriousness I am quit safe.  Even if the FBI flags it would be quite easy to fake a medical from what I have gathered.  To be fair I do think it would be best to delete the ultralight portions of the question for safety of others.

Comment: @blankip from my point of view mental health is an unfair field where perfectly intelligent and strong candidates are completely eliminated from military, piloting, being doctors.  So many professions are gone I think it is good that we can at least pilot ultralights.

Comment: @TylerDurden Second to last question here: http://www.usua.org/faq.htm#Q9  You don't actually need a license for part 103 ultralights.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

As Skip Miller said, you can take flight lessons. Up until you want to solo, you don't need a medical certificate. Often flight schools have "Discovery Flights" for a reduced cost that still allows you to fly left seat and get half an hour to an hour of flight. Careful though, its addicting.

Actual costs for this range from \$75 to over \$300 depending on the type of aircraft you are going to fly. Hourly rates for a Cessna 152 average around \$90 an hour, to a 172 up to \$150 an hour, and more sleek aircraft like a Cirrus SR-22 at \$300 per hour or more. Instructor rates go from \$35 per hour to \$65 per hour (typically) depending on the type of instruction.

Another option is to find a pilot who wants to build hours and go flying. They may let you fly the airplane around a little bit, but you'll most likely be flying right seat and probably won't let you do the more complicated phases of flight like take-off/landing and operations in controlled airspace. If you find a pilot willing to do this then you can share costs (split down the middle).

By the way don't get discouraged about your medical condition if you really want to fly. There are also a few options there too. First, you could go through the rather lengthy process with the FAA to have your case reviewed and if possible issued a special issuance medical certificate. Some of what you list are automatically disqualifying depending on the medications you may take, but [the AOPA has a good read on mental health](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources/health-conditions/mental-health) and getting medicals issued.

Second, you could get a sport pilot license, which also does not require a medical (just a drivers license). There may be hiccups with your conditions here too, so its best to talk to an AME or flight instructor before getting too deep.

---

Let me answer your specific question:

> Is there a way I can fly with a copilot without a pilot's license?

I take this to mean that the "copilot" is a non-pilot rated passenger. Unless you are a certificated pilot, then no. A "co-pilot" must be just that, a pilot. Otherwise they are just a passenger sitting in the front seat. Since that person is a passenger, you must be a fully licensed pilot to fly with them (students cannot take passengers).

If the copilot is a pilot rated individual, then yes, you can go flying with them (provided it is not a Part 135 flight). That person must be rated for the aircraft that you are flying and must meet currency requirements to carry passengers (you). [You as a passenger are allowed to manipulate the controls](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/are-pilots-allowed-to-let-passengers-fly-the-plane) under the supervision of the pilot provided the pilot is pilot in command and unless the pilot is a CFI, they are not providing instruction.

Comment: I do find this interesting.  Why is it okay for me to drive a car but not fly by default?  My only assumption is it has to do with 9/11 although I am just guessing.

Comment: No, not really. The effects of your medications become larger issues in the air. In a car, you can pull over, in an airplane, you can't. Also altitude can exacerbate side-effects due to reduced oxygen in the blood. Mix that in with the high likelyhood of death if incapacitated, you need to go through more rigorous hurdles to fly over driving. Crashes like [Germanwings 9525](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanwings_Flight_9525) also highlighted the dangers of individuals with severe depression in the cockpit...

Comment: That is fair although on the highway/interstate you can't really pull over either.  The oxygen and incapacitated points are good points though.

Comment: You can stop a moving vehicle if need be, even in a lane of travel (be it more dangerous) or continue a couple minutes to the next exit. An airplane is different, even with an airport directly below you it may take you 30+ minutes to get the aircraft down on the ground, in a critical phase of flight where you need the most skills/abilities.

Comment: @William, around here, all freeways come with a shoulder that is intended specifically to allow emergency stopping (with occasional exception of slow lane in uphill segments and sometimes opened for driving in a jam, but then the speed is not so high). Do the US ones not?

Comment: @JanHudec Almost all US ones do, but there are some freeways that have been expanded into the shoulder that don't have (much) room for stopping. Usually though there is an exit or pull-out every so often.

Comment: @JanHudec multi lane highways can not really have such in the US because if you are driving in the center there is no easy way to get to the shoulder at a moments notice https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Ruta_Panamericana_Buenos_Aires_Florida.jpg  He is also many US freeways don't have much space at if any

Comment: @William, in that screenshot past the junction there does seem to be a hard shoulder. Not very wide, but an average car should fit. And while it takes a couple of seconds to pull through all the lanes, it is still much faster than getting on the ground with an aircraft in the middle of cross-country flight.

Comment: `I take this to mean that the "copilot" is a non-pilot rated passenger` I read it the other way: that the co-pilot is rated, but not the OP. has the OP commented on this?

Comment: @Federico Either way I covered both cases :)

Comment: you did indeed, and I upvoted you for this!

Comment: You might add the glider option. They don't require a medical in the US either.

Comment: If you are serious about flying then you can see about getting approval from the FAA. If you are no longer taking drugs then you have as good a chance as any to get your student permit. But that is assuming all other things are normal as well. Contact the AOPA (Aircraft Owners and Pilots Association) or go to their web site. There is a huge source of information there and the names of people who you can ask that really know the answers.

Comment: @Federico  updated the question to say "as the copilot."  Part of me wonders if there are even two passenger planes that allow both copilot and pilot to control the plane.

Answer (score 7):

Take lessons with a CFI (Certified Flight Instructor).

Comment: Do you have costs or is that against the rules.

Comment: @William Costs vary so wildly based on location, type of aircraft, exact program details, etc... It would be out of scope to really cover it here. Shopping around locally will give you a better idea.

Comment: If you are going to look into taking lessons then look into joining a flying club. You may reduce your costs considerably. My club costs \$25/mo. I have access to several planes. I fly the Piper Arrow for \$136/hr with fuel. I get a credit card with the plane so I can fill it up wherever I go. The 172 (great training plane) costs \$80/hr. Most of the instructors approved by the club charge \$40/hour. Even Instrument instructors. You wont find those prices at the general Flying School. A school near me charges $160/hour for a 172 whether you have the instructor, or not.